# SQL Server: Computed Column with different datatypes

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to get a field to display the combination of a a field with data type int and another as nvarchar under Computed Column Specification, but am getting the following error:

`Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'y' to data type int.`

Computed Column Specification Forumula: [myNvarCharField] + ' ' + [myIntField]

Is it not possible to concatenate fields from different datatypes under the Computed Column Specification in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you would use a string and an int as computed column math.  Try this:

```
create table TestComputedCols
(
    someint int not null,
    somestring nvarchar(10) not null,
    combination as (somestring + ' ' + cast(someint as nvarchar))
)
```

Comment: Combination field should be a string.

Answer (score 1):

When you mix datatypes in an expression, implicit conversions happen according to "[datatype precedence"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx). Int is higher precedence than nvarchar so CAST the int first

```
...
MyComputedColumn AS [myNvarCharField] + ' ' + CAST([myIntField] AS nvarchar)
...
```